# Pipe not working in makefile

Tags: bash, makefile, grep

I've pulled out just the lines that matter:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash

leaks: build_eagle_test
    grep EagleMemory_Allocate -r eagle | perl -nle 'm/"(.*)"/; print $1' | sort | uniq > leaks.alloc.tmp
    grep "EagleMemory_Mock(" -r eagle_test | perl -nle 'm/"(.*)"/; print $1' | sort | uniq > leaks.alloc_test.tmp
```

When I run the lines in bash no problem. But from the make file it only pipes the `grep` into the out file (effectively ignoring the stages in between...)

Answer (score 11):

The `$` needs to be quoted as `$$`, e.g.,

```
SHELL := /bin/bash

leaks:
    grep EagleMemory_Allocate -r eagle | perl -nle 'm/"(.*)"/; print $$1' | sort | uniq > leaks.alloc.tmp
    grep "EagleMemory_Mock(" -r eagle_test | perl -nle 'm/"(.*)"/; print $$1' | sort | uniq > leaks.alloc_test.tmp
```

The problem is that Make doesn’t know anything about bash syntax and is ignoring all the `'"` quoting on the command line. It’s interpreting the `$1` as the value of the variable `1` in Make context—but there is no such variable, so it becomes a blank.

You can see this in the output of Make when it echoes the commands it runs from the original Makefile:

```
$ make
grep EagleMemory_Allocate -r eagle | perl -nle 'm/"(.*)"/; print ' | sort | uniq > leaks.alloc.tmp
grep "EagleMemory_Mock(" -r eagle_test | perl -nle 'm/"(.*)"/; print ' | sort | uniq > leaks.alloc_test.tmp
```

Notice that `$1` has disappeared.